# Correct design of table for classification data (e.g. drop-down data)

Tags: oracle, database-design

Let's say I have a table named Cat. Cats can be different breeds so there is a column in there to reference a specific breed from table named Breed.
I've seen some databases where these tables are designed as this:

```
Breed Table
ID (int) - auto incremential primary key
Value (varchar2(30))
```

```
1 Persian
2 Siamese
3 Maine Coon
```

Then let's say you need to set the breed in backend in several places, so you create a constant or enumerator which references the ID of Breed table:

```
const int PERSIAN = 1;
const int SIAMESE = 2;
const int MAINE_COON= 3;
```

I might be wrong but this seems like a bad practise. If you mess with the records (for example delete them by mistake and then recreate them) ID values will not match in different environments nor will they match with the constants you've created in backend.
So I was thinking if using code as primary key would be better solution but I've read that it's also not a great idea because referencing by number is faster. What I had in mind was something like that:

```
Breed Table
Code (varchar2(5)) - primary key
Value (varchar2(30))
```

```
PER Persian
SIA Siamese
MAI Maine Coon
```

Then if you were to store the constants in backend it would be:

```
const string PERSIAN = "PER";
const string SIAMESE = "SIA";
const string MAINE_COON = "MAI";
```

Which wouldn't change and wouldn't cause problems like the auto-incremential fields which can differ in different environments. 
Is my solution better? Are there better alternatives?
Sorry for the long post.

Comment: I would recommend using a string code as a PK in such cases. There is generally no real-world performance gain in using integers as opposed to short codes as PKs.

Comment: I agree 100% with @Steve. If the lookup value has meaning in your code, assign it to a known value rather than rely on a sequence. Your worries about the sequence on other platforms are legitimate.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.